# How to implement boolean isSorted for ArrayList elements being input from console?

Tags: java, boolean

**Is a List Sorted?**

*Write a program that checks if a list is already sorted. For a list to be sorted, the next element must NOT be smaller than the previous one*.

**Input**

On the first line - you will receive a number N.

On the next N lines, you will receive a list of numbers, separated by a comma

**Output**

There are N lines of output

for each list you receive, print 'true' if sorted or 'false' otherwise.

**Constraints**

1 <= N <= 10

1 <= list.length <= 20

**CODE:**

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Main {

      static public boolean isSorted(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
         boolean sorted = false;
         for (int i = 1; i< list.size(); i++){
         if (list.get(i-1)<list.get(i)) sorted = true;
      }
       return sorted;
   }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
     
     ArrayList<String> inputs = createList();
     ArrayList<Integer> resultList = transformList(inputs);
     printList(resultList);
  }

   public static ArrayList<String> createList() {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       int length = scanner.nextInt();
      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while(length-->-1){
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            list.add(input.replaceAll(",",""));
        }
        return list;
   }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> transformList(ArrayList<String> stringArrayList){
      ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i< stringArrayList.size(); i++){
          result.add(Integer.parseInt(stringArrayList.get(i)));
      }
       return result;
   }

   public static void printList(ArrayList<Integer> list){
      for (int  i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
          System.out.println(isSorted(list));
      }
   }
}
```

**Input**

3

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,8,9,9

1,2,2,3,2

**My OUTPUT gives an incorrect result:**

true

true

true

**Expected output is supposed to be looked like:**

true

true

false

Please, give me a hint to let me implement isSorted method correctly.

**NOTE:** *I need to implement it **without** *Guava Ordering class*.*

Comment: ``isSorted()`` returns true if any pair of elements appears sorted. I would suggest that you assume the list is sorted, then is any consecutive pair if not sorted, return false without checking anything else. Only if the loop finishes without returning, return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you just need an else statement. Once `sorted` is true, it never seems to return false if the other values are not in sorted order. Hence the issue with 1,2,2,3,2 . Where at first sorted is true but when comparing 3 with 2 sorted is suppose to be false, which you have not set as

```
static public boolean isSorted(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
         boolean sorted = false;
         for (int i = 1; i< list.size(); i++){
         if (list.get(i-1)<list.get(i))
              sorted = true;
         else{
             sorted = false;
          }

      }
       return sorted;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to traverse the whole list. As soon as you find that `list.get(i-1)>list.get(i)` which means that the list is not sorted, you can break out of the loop.

```
static public boolean isSorted(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
boolean sorted = true;
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
  if (list.get(i - 1) > list.get(i)) {
    sorted = false;
    break;
  }
}
return sorted;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should update the `sorted` value if not sorted.

```
static public boolean isSorted(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    boolean sorted = false;

    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        sorted = list.get(i - 1) <= list.get(i);
    }

    return sorted;
}
```